# Bad exchange rates in NZ banks?

Tags: exchange

Why in mobile bank in contrast to many other countries the rate is bad? I want to go to NZ and I cannot find NZD in my country. I want to bring usd. But I heard that the rate even in mobile bank is bad. Why is that? Does anybody use exchange in mobile bank and let me know the rate in working days?

Comment: What is mobile bank? Is it a New Zealand bank?

Comment: Typically I just use a local ATM to get cash. Also in NZ credit card acceptance is very good, so you may not need a lot of cash

Comment: I presume they mean mobile banking?

Comment: @MarkMayo Even if interpreted in that way, without knowing which bank's mobile banking, the question remains unanswerable and unclear without more context.

Comment: Any bank man!.....

Comment: How would you use mobile banking ? Pay with your cell phone with a service like Apple Pay? I don't see how mobile banking would be used to convert money?